# D3: How to set text inside a circle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm newbie with D3.js and I'm trying to put a text inside a circle but I am only able to do it with one of them and not with all the circles.

You can find all the code in this snipet

[image: Edit ORTG-DRTG-Scatterplot]

And the function where I create the circles and I try to put the text inside of is "setPointsToCanvas"

```
  setPointsToCanvas(canvas, data, scales, x_label, y_label, lang) {
    canvas
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 20) //Radius size, could map to another dimension
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return scales.xScale(parseFloat(d.value_x));
      }) //x position
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return scales.yScale(parseFloat(d.value_y));
      }) //y position
      .style("fill", "#FFC107")
      .on("mouseover", tipMouseOver)
      .on("mouseout", tipMouseOut);

//Ad label for each circle
canvas
  .data(data)
  //.enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return scales.xScale(parseFloat(d.value_x));
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return scales.yScale(parseFloat(d.value_y) - 0.9);
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name.substring(0, 3);
  })
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .style("font-size", "10pt")
  .style("fill", "#344761");

let tooltip = d3
  //.select("#" + this.props.idContainer)
  .select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip-player")
  .style("opacity", 0);

/**
 * We define this function inside of setPointsToCanvas to get access to canvas, data, scales and tooltip
 * @param {*} d
 * @param {*} iter
 */
function tipMouseOver(d, iter) {
  let players = data.filter(p => {
    if (p.value_x === d.value_x && p.value_y === d.value_y) {
      return p;
    }
  });
  let html = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    let text_x =
      lang === "es"
        ? String(parseFloat(players[i].value_x).toFixed(2)).replace(
            ".",
            ","
          )
        : parseFloat(players[i].value_x).toFixed(2);
    let text_y =
      lang === "es"
        ? String(parseFloat(players[i].value_y).toFixed(2)).replace(
            ".",
            ","
          )
        : parseFloat(players[i].value_y).toFixed(2);
    if (i > 0) html += "<hr>";
    html +=
      players[i].name +
      "<br><b>" +
      x_label +
      ": </b>" +
      text_x +
      "%<br/>" +
      "<b>" +
      y_label +
      ": </b>" +
      text_y +
      "%";
  }
  tooltip
    .html(html)
    .style("left", d3.event.pageX + 15 + "px")
    .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 28 + "px")
    .transition()
    .duration(200) // ms
    .style("opacity", 0.9); // started as 0!

  // Use D3 to select element, change color and size
  d3.select(this)
    //.attr("r", 10)
    .style("cursor", "pointer");
}

/**
 * We create this function inside of setPointsToCanvas to get access to tooltip
 */
function tipMouseOut() {
  tooltip
    .transition()
    .duration(500) // ms
    .style("opacity", 0); // don't care about position!
  //d3.select(this).attr("r", 5);
}
  }
```

And here you can see how I'm only able to get one text inside of one circle and not the text inside all of them.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't entering circles and text the same way, if you use the same approach you used for circles, you can create the text:
  `canvas.selectAll("text").data(data).enter().append("text")...`, however, if text already exists, you don't want to bind the data to these existing text elements (on the axes), so you could use `canvas.selectAll(null)` if just entering the text, or select by class name if you want to be able to re-select those specific text elements to update/exit the labels.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much for your appreciated help!!!

Comment: @AndrewReid, for the healthy of the `d3j.s` tag, please stop answering in the comments and use proper answers!

Comment: @PabloEM, feel free to add an answer (@José, you as well), there's more to be said than what I have written. I don't always have time to type up an answer I consider satisfactory - which for me means also explaining the why the wrong behavior is seen (in this case I didn't see it when I commented, though on re-read I'm a bit disappointed I didn't see it). Also, my initial take was that this was a possible duplicate, one that might be very tricky to find though, a comment could confirm the issue in the meantime (though I couldn't find one quickly, perhaps I'll add an answer tonight).

Comment: Yeah, I completly understand your point. But, on the other hand, your comments often are enough good and useful for the OP since he can fix his problem, although a more comprehensive answer would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the advice of @Pablo EM and thanks to @Andrew Reid for your appreciated help I publish the solution to my problem.

How @Andrew Reid said if I have problems with selectAll("text") I have to change it for another text grouper. How I had it, I changed by selectAll("textCircle") and everything works fine to me.

This is the code which writes the text inside each circle. This piede of code you can find it inside of "setPointsToCanvas" method.

```
//Ad label for each circle
canvas
  .selectAll("textCircle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return scales.xScale(parseFloat(d.value_x));
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return scales.yScale(parseFloat(d.value_y) - 0.9);
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name.substring(0, 3);
  })
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .style("font-size", "10pt")
  .style("fill", "#344761");
```

Now, here you've got an image of the final result:

[image]

If you access to the code through CodeSandBox posted before you can access to all the code and check how it works perfectly.